# Symfony Encore / Webpack {{ asset('build/app.js') }} not giving a valid path, error loading assets from the browser

Tags: symfony, webpack, twig, webpack-encore

Just started using Symfony and Encore/Webpack.

I followed Symfony's tutorial, my `webpack.config.js` is the following :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/scss/global.scss')

    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableLessLoader()
    .enablePostCssLoader()
    .enableReactPreset()

    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .enableBuildNotifications()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
        'materialize-css',
        './assets/js/global.js',
    ])
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And my basic view beiing :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body%}
Start

{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/global.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that even with both those files beeing almost the same as the tutorial from the doc, when testing on localhost, I get an error loading both css and js supposed output files.

My `manifest.json` has this and those files are present and well compiled at the right location :

```
"build/app.js": "/build/app.b9fa9f82050709ad01b8.js",
"build/global.css": "/build/global.ae6834d55ea0d4ff4100ad77aeffad72.css"
```

Output of chrome console :

```
GET http://localhost/my-website/public/build/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED         localhost/:11
GET http://localhost/my-website/public/build/global.css net::ERR_ABORTED     localhost/:6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just erased my project, reconfigurated the same way and it works now...